# How i can set up years view in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need to integrate a web design as shown in the image .  I need to use fullcalendar 5.4.0 and I need years view. I also did not find it in fullcalander docs, so I tried to use a custom view but that is not working.

[image]

> Code

```
var calendarElEvents = document.getElementById('calendarEvents');

// init calendar 
if (calendarElEvents) {
    var calendarEvents = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElEvents, {
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        locale: 'fr',
        headerToolbar: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: 'monthGridYear'
        },
        views: {
            monthGridYear: {
                type: 'dayGridMonth',
                duration: { years: 1 },
                buttonText: 'Years'
            }
        },
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        events: evenements,
        displayEventTime: false,
    });

    calendarEvents.render();
}
```

Comment: Where is your jQuery code?

Comment: i add it is above o.O

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: you don't need html markup, fullcalendar generate all in empty div with id

Comment: This isn't supported by fullCalendar. You would need to write a completely custom view as described here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js . If you look at the list of feature requests on fullCalendar's GitHub you'll see that people have also requested it before, so you could add your vote there towards getting it made - or even contribute some of the necessary code

Comment: thank you , yes i saw it in GitHub ,i will try if i can made it by custom view or try another package

Answer (score 0):

As I stumbled upon your message and I wanted to do something somewhat similar, I've created my own view. You can find the code here > https://github.com/Sebastien-Meiffren/Fullcalendar-MonthGridYear

It is not exactly what you wanted, but you can reuse my code (not perfect I know) to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

For the new Updated version of Fullcalendar@6.1.10

`right: 'multiMonthYear,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,dayGridDay,list'`

This 'multiMonthYear' answers your question